# How to fetch number from text in android

Tags: android, fetch

I want use register in my application and i should send password and verifyCode with SMS to users phones.
But i should **read verifyCode** from message and **set automatically** number into **verifyCode EditText**.

My message format :

> Hi, welcome to our service.
>
> your password 
> 12345
>
> your verifyCode 
> 54321

How can i do it? Please help me <3

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862162/otp-token-should-be-automatically-read-from-the-message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OTP (token) should be automatically read from the message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862162/otp-token-should-be-automatically-read-from-the-message)

Comment: @SagarGangawane, i want read from string file! please help me for this

Comment: @Kaushal28, i want read from string file! please help me for this

Comment: read from string file?  or read string from file?

Comment: @Kaushal28, i want read VerifyCode from string. for example : above text write into String message = "Hi, Welcome..."; fetch 54321 from verifyCode and show it into TextView

Comment: every time the string is fixed and only password and verify code is changing?

Comment: look at here - all thing that you need - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950808/how-to-extract-numbers-from-textview-android-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the number of digits are fixed in password and verify codes (Generally they are same as default values), We can extract digits from the string and then find substring which has verify code. This assumption is for simplicity.

```
String numberOnly= str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
String verifyCode = numberOnly.substring(6);
```

Here `String verifyCode = numberOnly.substring(6);` is getting last 5 digits of the string which is your verification code. You can also write `numberOnly.substring(6,10);` to avoid confusions.

But this is prone to errors like `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, So whenever you want to get substring which is starting from index `i` till the end of the string, always write `numberOnly.substring(i)`.

Comment: thanks man, what is `String verifyCode = numberOnly.substring(6);`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot ways to do this. You can use some complicated `regex` or use a simple `spilt` method.

Try this,

```
    String str = "Hi, welcome to our service.\n"
            + "\n"
            + "your password \n"
            + "12345\n"
            + "\n"
            + "your verifyCode \n"
            + "54321";

    // Solution #1
    String[] parts = str.split("\n");
    System.out.println(parts[3]);
    System.out.println(parts[6]);

    // Solution #2
    String PAT = "(password|verifyCode)\\s+(\\d+)";
    Pattern pats = Pattern.compile(PAT);
    Matcher m = pats.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        String grp = m.group(2);
        System.out.println(grp);
    }
```